# Solaris 11 installed, no updates?

Tags: security, unix, solaris

I was messing around with solaris and decided to give Solaris 11 a try so I downloaded it from the Oracle website. After installing the OS, I went into the package manager and did an update. It told me that there were to available updates! I find this hard to believe considering that it's running a vulnerable version of firefox and java, its own in-house software product! Many of the other software products that came with the default install are also out of date and vulnerable. Is this normal for an Oracle install, or did I do something wrong with the upgrade process? I typed "pkg update" at the prompt, and I noticed that it did call out to pkg.oracle.com looking for updates. I find it bizarre that there are no updates available for an OS that was released a couple months ago with vulnerable software...

Comment: You should try open Indiana instead. It has a real community, and has public updates.

Answer (score 5):

There are [maintenance updates](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E24456/gljrq.html) available for Solaris 11 but I assume you downloaded it under the [OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/solaris-cluster-express-license-167852.html) license agreement which states:

*Our technical support organization will not provide technical support, phone support, or updates to you for the Programs licensed under this agreement.*

That said, firefox isn't an Oracle in-house project but a Mozilla one. You can download a tarball of its [latest release](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+desktop/development)

Similarly, you likely can download or recompile from source most third party software products should you need them in their latest release.

Update:

- It is always possible to install newer versions of java for Solaris from archives (`tar.gz`) available here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

- Should you want to compile FOSS from source, you can start with the Solaris Userland consolidation available here:

https://github.com/oracle/solaris-userland

- or directly install already built updated packages from the Solaris 11.3 repository. See:

https://blogs.oracle.com/solarisfoss/selected-foss-evaluation-packages-may-2017

Answer (score 2):

The last time I used Solaris(10), updates were only available to (paid)subscribers.